# Should exemplary answers bounties be immediate?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'll make this short and sweet. I recently added a bounty to [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10964/how-would-i-limit-feudalism) question because some of the answers there were great, though I could only accept one. When it asked me why I was adding the bounty I clicked the "One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty" reason. The problem is extremely minor, but it made me wait 23 hours to award the bounty to said exemplary answers. While I waited and I didn't die (not like I thought I was going to anyway) it was an annoyance.

Therefore I suggest we add the option to immediately award the bounty or wait for a day when someone picks the "One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty" option. Thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been asked and answered before (on other stack exchange sites so I can't close as duplicate, this is the first time it's been asked here as far as I know).

For example see here: [Should the 24-hour timeout apply to bounties awarded for "exemplary answer"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116072/should-the-24-hour-timeout-apply-to-bounties-awarded-for-exemplary-answer)

Comment: I actually only searched stack overflow, scifi, and Worldbuilding for the answer. I'll delete the question

Comment: @DustinJackson Please don't delete. It's useful to have here for reference.

Answer (score 4):

Don't you want to draw attention to those outstanding answers so people who missed them the first time around will vote?  Bounties aren't just about you giving a reward to another user; they're also about generating some extra attention.  That's why they show up on the main page with the blue marker and why they have their own tab (though, granted, the latter is more of a factor on bigger sites -- but we'll be big before too long!).

Yes, it means there's a risk that you won't award your bounty and the auto-awarder will do the wrong thing.  It would be nice if, *for this bounty reason*, you could either designate when you set the bounty (but it won't be awarded until later) or the auto-awarder didn't run at all (because, by definition, it won't award the correct answer).  But I'd kind of like to see those bounty-worthy questions be labeled as such for more than the few minutes it would take you to award it manually.

(I tried to post this yesterday *just* after the question was deleted.  Now that the question is back I'm adding this extra bit of reasoning even though there's already a pointer to MSE.)